# Suggest any good text editor for Mac for writing in multiple languages

Tags: software, tools

I have been using **iBook author**, for a time and the simple Mac **TextEdit** along with openOffice **TextDocument**. And I recently downloaded **Evernote** in expectation of more (but that's something else and not writer specific). I also have been looking in an appstore for the same.

I want some suggestion on good text editor that I can use for writing in multiple languages (specially English, Hindi, Arabic, and Urdu). Other language support would be great.

Comment: What will you be using this to write?

Comment: @NeilFein means?

Comment: Will you be writing fiction? Non-fiction? Short essays or entire books? Do you need version control features? Knowing things like this will help people make better recommendations.

Comment: What is it about the editors you've tried that's unsatisfactory?  (Just the language issue, or are there others?)  Knowing more about what you're looking for, and looking to avoid, will help us to answer.  (Plus, what @NeilFein said.)

Comment: @NeilFein I'll be writing entire books, short stories poems and technical papers. That'll include my research on the topic in it, like all the images video and graphics.

Comment: @MonicaCellio i have been pretty satisfied with iBookAuthor since yet for book and poem writing but it's something not not a good place for technical papers kind of writing plus I want to look at some change as it's been long time using it. I think "Scrivener" should be the next. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been writing on the Mac for a number of years now. Over that time, I've settled into using [Scrivener](http://literatureandlatte.com) for project organization, version control, and major publishing; and Sublime Text 2 + [Markdown Editing for Sublime Text 2](http://brettterpstra.com/2012/05/17/markdown-editing-for-sublime-text-2-humble-beginnings/) for most of the actual writing. I use [Marked](http://markedapp.com) for the publishing right now (I mostly [blog](http://publius225.wordpress.com) at Wordpress, and this workflow lets me quickly build reasonably complex blog posts).

Unless you're technically-inclined, I'd recommend just using Scrivener. See this [introductory video](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/videos/ScrivIntroSmall.mov) for a good overview. At its core, Scrivener lets you break up big projects into small chunks, organize them in whatever way suits you, and then get writing.

It's also got powerful version control (I recommend using the [Snapshots](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/videos/Snapshots2.mov) feature liberally), an attractive full-screen writing mode, and excellent publishing support (output to .doc, .pdf, ebook formats, .txt, MultiMarkdown, and god knows what else). My favorite feature is that Scrivener allows you to bring your research materials directly into the project file, for easy access later. Very useful for term papers.

It uses the standard Mac text-handling engine. If OS X supports the languages you mention, I think Scrivener should too. If in doubt, try the free demo.

The learning curve can be somewhat steep. It's worth it, however, if you're managing a large writing project with a complex structure or one with lots of background information.

If you don't intend to do too much writing, or only write simple projects, you might be better off sticking with Word, Pages, or even just TextEdit at the start. The tool is just that, a tool. If it's getting in the way of your writing, then go back to a simpler tool.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/). I can't find anything in the documentation about those languages specifically, but it doesn't rule them out either. Free to try for a month, so you've got nothing to lose.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to IA Writer too. So simple, so beautiful. And with iCloud support you can use iDevices to continue your work where you left off.

Comment: + 1 @Tiziano and Thanks for the suggestion.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs is on the Mac. Just type "emacs" at the terminal.

Emacs supports Unicode and bidirectional text (Arabic), etc.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/International.html#International

It also comes with a project planner called org-mode (which also includes its own complete publishing system), artist-mode for ASCII art, dired file manager and a shell so you never have to leave Emacs ever, a browser, the French Revolutionary metric calendar, and a built-in psychotherapist.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out Mellel: http://www.mellel.com/

Apparently it's good at RTL languages which you mentioned you will be using (Arabic, Urdu) and it's cheaper than MS Word etc.

That having been said, I use Scrivener, as various others have mentioned; but I haven't had much experience with multi-lingual documents.